# Jest for Angular cobertura file rename

Tags: angular, jestjs

I am trying to integrate Jest in my Angular application. As per jest configuration, I can configure the reporters but it doesn't allow me to set the output file name for Cobertura. To configure other custom reporters I can use reporters field & they allow providing extra config.
How do I name my file as cobertura.xml.

Please help!

```
coverageReporters: [
        "text",
        "lcov",
        "cobertura"
    ],
    reporters: ["default", "jest-junit"],
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem!

I solved using a custom lib (as you mentioned yourself), I believe in JS / Regex for solution or something of the sort.

I used this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-sonar-reporter

***UPDATE***

> A list of reporter names that Jest uses when writing coverage reports.
>   Any istanbul reporter can be used.

```
coverageReporters [array<string>] #
Default: ["json", "lcov", "text"]
```

https://jest-bot.github.io/jest/docs/configuration.html

Answer (score 5):

By default cobertura report file is named - `cobertura-coverage.xml`. You can override this by providing additional configuration as tuple.

```
coverageReporters: [
  'text', 
  'lcov', 
  ['cobertura', {file: 'cobertura.xml'}]
]
```

Look for `CoverageReporterWithOptions`.

Ref: https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#coveragereporters-arraystring--string-options